# rails to .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am planning a web site/store that needs to run on a windows machine.
I have some experience in RoR but for this project I guess .NET is the solution.
What is the learning curve like to go over to .NET MVC for an experienced programmer (RoR, Ruby, lots of C/++)?

Answer (score 1):

The concepts will be the same but you will find that the implementation is quite different.  Your C++ experience will help you as you will be able to hit the ground running with C# but still I think you will need to read up a bit to get familiar with .NET (the languages, compilers, framework, and runtime).

Learning curves are very subjective things - it all depends on your aptitude for software development plus how much time you are willing to invest in learning something new.

Answer (score 1):

- Routing constraints (global.asax)
- Action filters (via action attributes)
- Linq to SQL
- C# 3.0 features like lambda expressions, anonymous initializers, and implicit typing (var)
- DataContractSerializer or JavascriptSerializer for serialization stuff
- Donut caching, authentication, CSRF and a few other concepts that will need your attention when building the app